# Get non matching records from School table (highlighted)

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Tables]

I want to get the highlighted records from table 'School' which has the subject not in Tution. Tried left join which is going wrong for some reason. Can someone help please. I am using sql server.

Comment: Hint:  `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Wich SGBD do you use ?

Comment: Show us your current query attempt!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Student, Subject, Marks FROM School
EXCEPT
SELECT Student, Subject, Marks FROM Tution
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Try that query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TUTION  
WHERE MARKS NOT IN
(SELECT MARKS FROM SCHOOL WHERE MARKS IN(90,70) AND STUDENT NOT IN('PETER',JOHN'))
```

Comment: 1st Unclosed quotation mark, 2nd it will return the desired outputs?